# The most reliable way to get ERC20 token price

Tags: tokens, erc-20, uniswap, price

What is the most reliable way to get ERC20 token price?

I'm thinking about using [Coingecko](https://www.coingecko.com/en/api/documentation) API, but not sure if it's safe to use in the production environment.
Another way to get the token price is to fetch it straight from the Uniswap pair contract. It feels more reliable as there is no middle man, but aggregator like Coingecko price is more accurate.

Comment: Where do you want to get the price? In a Solidity smart contract? In a JavaScript script? In Rust? In a client app? On a server?

Comment: Using an oracle like Chainlink is another option.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg, in a JavaScript script

Comment: I believe they both work, as there is no a definition on which price is more "correct"